# Copy/paste bar not showing up for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, copy-paste

I have an EditText in my layout that works fine, except for one thing: when I long press on existing text, the contextual action bar with the Select All, Copy, and Cut options doesn't appear at the top of the screen. I get the little Paste button at the selection point, though.

This only happens in the landscape orientation. I can see the copy/paste bar just fine in portrait.

I have made no programmatic changes to the EditText and my XML is pretty vanilla.

One thing to note is I have set windowSoftInputMode to "stateHidden" in my AndroidManifest.xml

I am largely self-taught, so it seems like I've found a hole in my knowledge. How can I make the copy/paste bar appear in landscape also?

Additional info: I am testing on Kitkat [4.4, API 19], targeting Android L [4.5, API 20] when compiling, and my minimum API is Jellybean [4.1, API 16]